# Android studio is not accepting string. When I want to put a string into a class from edittext

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I commented where it stops working, can someone please help!This code is a roman numeral converter. I got the number to roman working, but the roman to number just crashes the app. If anyone knows why or how the code is crashing please lmk, and how to fix it! I been working on this for 8 hours straight and still can't find what is wrong. I am new to android studio this also may be why. Thanks.

Logcat error:

```
2022-01-27 13:27:33.286 1575-1575/com.example.numeralromancalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.numeralromancalculator, PID: 1575
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6412)
        at com.example.numeralromancalculator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

```
convertToNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //converter class is called
                converter cn = new converter();

                //checks if input is int or not
                boolean digitCheck = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(inputRoman.getText());


//App Crashes HERE
                if (digitCheck == false){
                    //the input from the user
                    String theRom = inputRoman.getText().toString();

                    //string output to user
                    int outputNum = cn.romanToInteger(theRom);

                    //outputs number to roman conversion
                    numOutput.setText(outputNum);
                }else{

                    //statement to print to screen
                    String reTry = "Invalid: Try Again";

                    //Outputs that users input is not valid
                    numOutput.setText(reTry);
                }

            }
        });

        //If Convert tto Roman button is clicked
        convertToRoman.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //converter class is called
                converter nc = new converter();

                //checks if input is int or not
                boolean digitCheck = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(inputNum.getText());

                if (digitCheck == true){
                    //the input from the user
                    int theNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputNum.getText().toString());

                    //string output to user
                    String theRoman = nc.toRoman(theNumber);

                    //outputs number to roman conversion
                    romanOutput.setText(theRoman);
                }else{

                    //statement to print to screen
                    String reTry = "Invalid: Try Again";

                    //Outputs that users input is not valid
                    romanOutput.setText(reTry);
                }

            }
        });

        }

    }
```

```
public class converter {

    public String toRoman(int numberInput) {

        //checks if integer conversion is possible
        if (numberInput < 1 || numberInput > 3999) {
            return "Sorry, Not Possible";
        }

        //Roman letter total
        String returnValue = "";

        //while statements to check for roman letters, and adds to total
        //descending order

        while (numberInput >= 1000) {
            returnValue += "M";
            numberInput -= 1000;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 900) {
            returnValue += "CM";
            numberInput -= 900;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 500) {
            returnValue += "D";
            numberInput -= 500;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 400) {
            returnValue += "CD";
            numberInput -= 400;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 100) {
            returnValue += "C";
            numberInput -= 100;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 90) {
            returnValue += "XC";
            numberInput -= 90;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 50) {
            returnValue += "L";
            numberInput -= 50;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 40) {
            returnValue += "XL";
            numberInput -= 40;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 10) {
            returnValue += "X";
            numberInput -= 10;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 9) {
            returnValue += "IX";
            numberInput -= 9;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 5) {
            returnValue += "V";
            numberInput -= 5;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 4) {
            returnValue += "IV";
            numberInput -= 4;
        }
        while (numberInput >= 1) {
            returnValue += "I";
            numberInput -= 1;
        }

        //return a string value of the numeral
        return returnValue;
    }

//APP CRASHES USING THIS CLASS

    public int romanToInteger(String roman) {
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < roman.length(); i++) {
            char c = roman.charAt(i);
            switch (c) {
                case 'I':
                    number = (i != roman.length() - 1 && (roman.charAt(i + 1) == 'V' || roman.charAt(i + 1) == 'X'))
                            ? number - 1
                            : number + 1;
                    break;
                case 'V':
                    number += 5;
                    break;
                case 'X':
                    number = (i != roman.length() - 1 && (roman.charAt(i + 1) == 'L' || roman.charAt(i + 1) == 'C'))
                            ? number - 10
                            : number + 10;
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    number += 50;
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    number = (i != roman.length() - 1 && (roman.charAt(i + 1) == 'D' || roman.charAt(i + 1) == 'M'))
                            ? number - 100
                            : number + 100;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    number += 500;
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    number += 1000;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return number;
    }

        }
```

Comment: Please add the error message from your logcat

Comment: Done, can you please check it now

Answer (score 0):

It seems like value from your method is interpreted as resource Id, so make sure, the type is String:

```
 //string output to user
 String outputNum = Integer.toString(cn.romanToInteger(theRom));

 //outputs number to roman conversion
 numOutput.setText(outputNum);
```

Comment: UR THE BEST! I BEEN TRYING TO SOLVE THIS! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the method setText you have to pass variables of the type String to it as a parameter but the type of numOutput is Int. You have to change it to String. You can use String.valueOf(outputNum) and pass the result as a parameter to setText.

```
ConvertToNum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

//converter class is called
converter cn = new converter();

//checks if input is int or not
boolean digitCheck = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(inputRoman.getText());


//App Crashes HERE
if (digitCheck == false){
//the input from the user
String theRom = inputRoman.getText().toString();

//string output to user
int outputNum = cn.romanToInteger(theRom);

//outputs number to roman conversion
//***************************************************ANSWER!!! You must use String for "setText"! Not Int
// numOutput.setText(outputNum);
numOutput.setText(String.valueOf(outputNum));
//***************************************************

}else{

//statement to print to screen
String reTry = "Invalid: Try Again";

//Outputs that users input is not valid
numOutput.setText(reTry);
}
}
});
```